# Qualtrics change text of Pick Group Rank

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

I'm creating a Qualtrics survey that uses the Pick Group & Rank question type. However, the box of items is automatically labeled "Items" and I would like to change this to "Issues". Is there any Javascript or HTML that can be used to change this text? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried by posting your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same question for a Qualtrics survey I'm working on -- and I'm a total newb on this stuff -- but I miraculously discovered a code that works(!).

Add the following to the bottom of your question text (in HTML mode):

```
<style>
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items h2 { 
font-size: 0;
}
</style>
<h5>Issues</h5>
```

where "Issues" is what you want in place of "Items".  I think this code shrinks "Items" to size 0 text and you are simply adding another heading on top of where "Items" is.

FYI: You can replace "h5" with h1, h2, h3, h4, or h6, depending on the size of header that you want, but I found h5 to be a good size for what I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure anything out in time, but I'll keep this in mind if this situation happens again! Thanks!